# Is there any way to clean docker files while keeping its cache?

Tags: docker, caching

I'm running a lot of builds using Docker on Linux. Eventually a lot of data is piling up, for example this is what I see in `docker system df`:

```
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          247       0         45.03GB   45.03GB (100%)
Containers      0         0         0B        0B
Local Volumes   59        0         0B        0B
Build Cache     118       0         3.487kB   3.487kB
```

Is there a way to clean up unused images, containers, and local volumes while maintaining the Docker cache?

I tried a `docker system prune` but I lose some caches that can help me in new builds.

Comment: I created this command to run in my cron for weekly cleaning, it works well:


`$ { /usr/bin/docker system df && /usr/bin/docker system prune -a --filter "until=$(date -d '-30 days' +%s)" --force | (while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$(data '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') - $line"; done) } &>> /var/log /docker/log-cron-docker.log`


This command cleans up old images that are older than 30 days and unused.